# Why is component shown just for a fraction of a second?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

As a beginner in Vue, I am struggling with a problem that  - even this should not be too hard - I can't solve. The principle is as follows:

I want to create a survey that consists of different topics. The user should be able to choose between these topics (component A and component B). This works fine.

But: When I click on the button "Show Component C", this component is only displayed for a fraction of a second. Why is this, what mistake have I made and how can I solve the problem?

Thanks a lot for your help!

**App.vue**

```
<button @click="setSelectedComponent('ComponentA')">Component A</button>
<button @click="setSelectedComponent('ComponentB')">Component B</button>
  
  <component-b 
  v-if="selectedComponent === 'ComponentB'"
  > </component-b>
  
  <component-a 
  v-if="selectedComponent === 'ComponentA'"
  ></component-a>
 

  <start 
  v-if="selectedComponent === 'form-empty'"
  ></start>

</template>


<script>
import ComponentB from './components/ComponentB.vue';
import ComponentA from './components/ComponentA.vue';
import Start from './components/Start.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    ComponentB,
    ComponentA,
    Start,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedComponent: 'form-empty',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setSelectedComponent(cmp) {
      this.selectedComponent = cmp;
    },
  
    }
  }  
</script>
```

**Start.vue**

```
<template>
  <form>
    <div>
      <h1>Which Component Do You Want To Select?</h1>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

**

**Component A**

```
<template>
  <form>
    <h1>Component A</h1>

    <div class="form-control">
      <input type="range" min ="0" max="100" v-model=value>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button @click="evaluateForm">Save Data</button>
    </div>
   
    <h4>Value: {{value}}</h4>
  </form>
  <component-c v-if="varia === 'yes'"></component-c>


</template>

<script>
import ComponentC from './ComponentC.vue';
export default {
  components: {
    ComponentC
  },
  methods: {
    evaluateForm() {
      this.varia='yes'

    }


  },
  
  computed: {
    result() {
      return parseInt(this.abc) + parseInt(this.cde)

      
    }
    

  },
    data() {
        return {
            value: '',
            varia: '' 


            }
      
            }
}
</script>
```

**Component B**

```
<template>
  <form>
    <h1>Component B</h1>

    <div>
      <input type="range" min ="0" max="100" v-model=value>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button @click="evaluateForm">Save Data</button>
    </div>

    <h4>Value: {{value}}</h4>
  </form>
    <component-c v-if="varia === 'yes'"></component-c>
</template>


<script>
import ComponentC from './ComponentC.vue';
export default {
  components: {
    ComponentC
  },
  methods: {
    evaluateForm() {
      this.varia='yes'
    }
  },
  
  computed: {
    result() {
      return parseInt(this.abc) + parseInt(this.cde) 
    }
  },
    data() {
        return {
            value: '',
            varia: ''
            }
            }
}
</script>
```

**Component C**

```
<template>
  <form>
    <div class="form-control">
      <h1>The value is: </h1>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to host a replication of this issue somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I tested this out locally and the problem comes from the fact that you are using `<form>` in ComponentA and ComponentB. If you switch those to `<div>` or `<form @submit.prevent>` you'll see that it works as you expected.

Here is some documentation on the `<form>` element to learn more about how it works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: I think that I need to change the value of "SelectedComponent" so that there is no condition for components A or B anymore. For this reason I tried to emit an event so that the variable "SelectedComponent" in App.vue is changed so that the conditions are no longer valid for components A and B. But unfortunately this does not work either. Component A (or B) is no longer displayed, but neither is component C.

I know I still have a lot to learn. But could you give me some more advice here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: To get your original code to work follow my advice: switch the `form` tags to `div` or add the `@submit.prevent` handler to your `form`. I got it working on my end.

Comment: It works in the sense that component C is actually displayed, but component A (or B) is also displayed. But only component B should be displayed :/

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you are trying to do. What should be displayed when I click on the `ComponentA Button` and then the `Save Data Button`? Right now I see 
https://i.imgur.com/5muOPjW.png
This is what "should" be happening based on what you've coded.

Comment: I made it available for testing online: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-app-lzljhy?file=src/App.vue

This is working as intended. If you had it in mind to do something else, you'd have to describe it in greater detail.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The code works exactly the same for me as it does for you. But additionally, I just want that when the button "Sava Data" is clicked, ONLY Component C is displayed ("The value is"), and not still above the component that contains the slider. 

And to achieve this I have emitted an event that should set a variable in App.vue when the "Save Data" button was clicked. And when this variable is set, Component C should be displayes. And at the same time "SelectedComponent" should be set to a different value, so that Component A / Component B is not shown anymore.

Comment: Ok. I'm glad I was able to answer the original question for you. As you're new to StackOverflow, you should mark my response as the answer and create a new question to ask specific questions about the new problem you want to solve.

Comment: For fun, I made the changes you wanted for your new question here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-app-lzljhy?file=src%2FApp.vue
I added a couple of improvements to simplify App.vue. But again please submit a new question as the original issue has been resolved.

Comment: All clear. Thanks again for your help. I need to go a little deeper into the concept of Vue, I guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Component A**

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <h1>Component A</h1>

    <div>
      <input type="range" min ="0" max="100" v-model=value>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button @click="evaluateForm">Save Data</button>
    </div>
   
    <h4>Value: {{value}}</h4>
  </div>
  


</template>

<script>
export default {
  
  methods: {
    evaluateForm() {
      this.$emit('xxx');

    }


  },
  
  computed: {
    result() {
      return parseInt(this.abc) + parseInt(this.cde)

      
    }
    

  },
    data() {
        return {
            value: '',

            }
      
            }
}
</script>
```

**App.Vue**

```
    <template>
  <button @click="setSelectedComponent('ComponentA')">Component A</button>
  <button @click="setSelectedComponent('ComponentB')">Component B</button>

  <component 
  
  :is="selectedComponent"
  
  ></component>

  <component-a
  
  @xxx="startComponentC"
   v-if="varia === 'yes'"
  ></component-a>

  <component-c
  
   v-if="varia === 'yes'"
  
  ></component-c>


</template>


<script>
import ComponentB from "./components/ComponentB.vue";
import ComponentA from "./components/ComponentA.vue";
import Start from "./components/Start.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    ComponentB,
    ComponentA,
    Start,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedComponent: "start",
      varia:""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setSelectedComponent(cmp) {
      this.selectedComponent = cmp;
    },
    startComponentC() {
      this.varia="yes"
      this.selectedComponent="stopConditionforComponentAandB"
    }
  },
};
</script>
```